# Is there a way to generate a COM interop assembly that targets .net standard or .net core?

Tags: .net-core, com-interop, .net-standard

Since .NET Core 3.0 supports COM, is there a way to create an interop DLL that targets .NET Standard or .NET Core 3?

I used to create these interop libraries that target .NET framework via [Tlbimp.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbimp-exe-type-library-importer).

Comment: It is a bit of a mystery how they plan to move ahead with this.  But there's just no priority, this is Windows only and the interop library generated by tlbimp.exe or the IDE works just fine.  Have you tried?

Comment: @HansPassant, the autogenerated dll seems to target .NET framework. It works fine when you target this autogenerated dll directly (it seems they rely on the compatibility shim feature). If I pack this dll into a nuget package and reference that, things don't work. I thought that if I can make the interop dll be .net standard, then things might work.

Comment: So you asked the wrong question.

Answer (score -1):

From a developer command prompt, I run a command like this:

```
TlbImp.exe COMOBJECT.dll
```

You're correct that the generated interop file appears to be for .NET framework.  I see this using ILSpy on the generated DLL.  However when I run my code as .NET Core 3.1 I do not see any of the .NET Framework files loaded in to my process.  I confirm this in Studio from:  Debug / Windows / Modules.  That shows all the loaded DLL's in my debug process.